# Outlook wont open - Inbox repair, file in shared drive

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

We have an issue in which Outlook will not open on a users machine if you try to open it then you get the following error:
[error mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTv7A.png)

When you click ok the file location is for a file in a shared location which is wrong. if this runs then it finds no errors, outlook still does not open. If we do the same with the file in the local user app data it is the same result.
We have removed the PST file from the location - No luck
Reinstalled office - No Luck
Ne office profile - No Luck.

does anyone please have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Can this issue be reproduced if you log in to your email account on other computers?

I encountered the same issue in Outlook 365 as you, but I found that I can normally add the same email account to another Outlook client. I searched a lot about this error but have not found any official documents explaining this issue. I'm afraid that this may be related to the Outlook version,please keep an eye on the announcement or update from Microsoft.

Here is a similar thread, for your reference:[Outlook 2016 opens with "Something is wrong with one of your data files and outlook needs to close."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2cc0180b-eb71-47d5-bfd1-20c4e479fff0/outlook-2016-opens-with-quotsomething-is-wrong-with-one-of-your-data-files-and-outlook-needs-to?forum=outlook)